# Rearrange dataframe in pandas - move sets of rows into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe file `df` that looks like:

[image: input dataframe]

which I am trying to convert into:

[image]

My attempt was to use the numpy.reshape function:

```py
df2 = np.reshape(df, (10, 2))
```

But this gives `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 24 into shape (9,2)` as the indices change, and change the size of the dataframe in the rearrangment. Is there a simplee Python function to make such a rearrangement in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the column "Unnamed:0"? if not, a simple way would be to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:df[range(3)].values[[0,2,4]].flatten(),1:df[range(3)].values[[1,3,5]].flatten()}).T
```

if you need the column 'Unnamed: 0', you could add the following line:

```
df['Unnamed: 0'] = [0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Unnamed': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
     0: ['A','D','G','J','M','P'],
     1: ['B','E','H','K','N','Q'],
     2: ['C','F','I','L','O','R']}
)

new_df = df.T
print(new_df)
```

```
         0  1  2  3  4  5
Unnamed  0  1  2  3  4  5
0        A  D  G  J  M  P
1        B  E  H  K  N  Q
2        C  F  I  L  O  R
```